# 90's sci-fi book, female character's hair changes styles with her mood, characters travel and wake up a man from a cryo unit

Tags: story-identification, books

I think it was part of a series.

- One female character had hair that changed styles depending on her circumstances or moods.
- The characters traveled to different places (not time travel but some other way I think).
- On one of their journeys they found a man in a cryo-unit whom they woke up.

Comment: Changing hair styles sounds like it was a comic book. Was it?

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of Farscape or Andromeda. Both series had characters (Jools / Beka) with Kaleidoscope hair (http://allthetropes.wikia.com/wiki/Kaleidoscope_Hair), characters that travel across the galaxy and at least one episode where they find people in cryo-units.

Comment: When you say "traveled to different places", are we talking about different countries on Earth? Different planets? Different worlds? Did they travel using some vehicle? Spaceship? Teleportation?

Comment: I think they may have travelled to different earths. It definitely wasn't farscape or Andromeda. I don't remember them traveling using vehicles but there may have been a machine thing they went into or stood in.

Comment: Mr Lister- it was a book I read but I guess the story could have been a comic strip before.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be Peter Hamilton's [*Naked God*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_God) series (1996-1999)? It doesn't sound exact, but has all of the elements you listed.

There was a female singer who could change her appearance and hooked up with a re-incarnated Al Capone.

Science fiction story where characters traveled to many different planets.

There are people who go into "zero-tau" pods and wake up for a short time every 20 years or so. I think they were called time travelers or something like that.

Comment: thanks Salem Lowe. I will google them and see if they are the right books.